# type org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTrackerCustomizer does not take parameters

Tags: java, websphere, osgi, maven-3, osgi-bundle

I'm working on osgi application which uses com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar because I need to use WebSphere with JMX.

When I import as dependency this jar I get error in bundle activators:

```
public abstract class AbstractServiceTracker implements ServiceTrackerCustomizer<Object, Object> {
...
private ServiceTracker<Object, Object> tracker = new ServiceTracker<>(bc, bc.createFilter(builder.toString()), this);
```

I get error in Netbeans `type ServiceTrackerCustomizer does not take parameters` and `cannot infer type arguments for ServiceTracker<>`

i suppose that this is a classpath issue. When i remove com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar it's working fine. In this case what are the options to solve this problem?

Comment: You must be using an old version of the OSGi compendium JAR. Generics were added in OSGi Release 4.3. Or, remove the generics from your code.

Comment: I use in my parent pom `<groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>` Maybe in com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar I have old version?

Comment: It turns out that there is a file `com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0\org\osgi\util\tracker\ServiceTrackerCustomizer.class` Maybe I need to wait for new WebSphere version? Is there any way to isolate this part of the code?

Comment: It's probably not necessary for you to compile against `com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar`. Just remove it from the classpath.

Comment: Can you give me some information how to do this in Netbeans?

Comment: No, I'm not a NetBeans user. Maybe somebody else can help.