# Generate custom com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

Is there any way to generate custom com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar? I want to remove org.osgi.* packages from default jar file provided in WebSphere package.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done manually, but the jars cannot be re-generated in any way.  However, manually altering product binaries is a violation of the user agreement.

Also, removing any packages (especially `org.osgi.*`) would break the product.  Packages would not be included in WebSphere product binaries unless they were needed.

Comment: I found this problem when I use com.ibm.ws.admin.client_8.5.0.jar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34466700/type-org-osgi-util-tracker-servicetrackercustomizer-does-not-take-parameters  Can you propose some solution?

Comment: It sounds like a separate question, which is how to control which jars are on the class path in NetBeans. I would recommend searching for how to do that or opening a new question if you don't find anything.

Comment: Can you give some answer into the post from the link, please?